# how can i check crypted password in login page?

Tags: php, encryption, crypt

i encrypted my password with crypt() function.
when a user wants to login how can i check the password stored in database with this one entered?

**for Ex:**

```
$pass = "fgyi34".$pass."@1187Gh";

$hashed_password = crypt($pass);
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199244/using-crypt-and-verifying-not-sure-how-it-works)?

Comment: You need to crypt the password the users fills in the login form before runnig sql query

Comment: i know but each time it give a different output

Answer (score 0):

**For a new user.**
`crypt` the password and store it in the database.

**For an existing user**
`crypt` the password and store it in a variable when the user clicks the submit button, compare the crypted password with the earlier crypted password on your database. If the password doesn't match, display a message to the user that password is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Store $hashed_password into the database on registration.

On login check the crypted password with the stored one in a mysql query

Answer (score 0):

Crypt password can not be reversed so follow the below steps for password encryption :

1) generate a random number and encrypt that. 
2) After encryption save that in a database column field.
3) at the time of login, cross check the entered password and again encrypt that.
4) Check this new password with hashed password.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [`Manual`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) please.

> An optional salt string to base the hashing on. If not provided, the
>   behaviour is defined by the algorithm implementation and can lead to
>   unexpected results

**Example #1**

```
<?php
  $hashed_password  = crypt( 'mypassword' ); // let the salt be automatically generated

  /*
    You should pass the entire results of crypt() as the salt for comparing a
    password, to avoid problems when different hashing algorithms are used. (As
    it says above, standard DES-based password hashing uses a 2-character salt,
    but MD5-based hashing uses 12.)
  */
  if ( crypt( $user_input, $hashed_password ) == $hashed_password ) {
    echo "Password verified!";
  }
?>
```

So whenever users try to login, get the crypted `password` from database with their `username` and compare both `user input` and `hashed password` with `crypt`.

**Example #2**

```
<?php
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];

  $passhash = "SELECT `password` FROM `table` WHERE `username` = '{$username}'";
  // execute the query and get the hashed password

  if ( $passhash ) {
    if ( crypt( $password, $passhash ) == $passhash ) {
      echo "Password verified!";
    }
  }
?>
```